# How to execute postbuild script after all package script events?

Tags: node.js, angular, package.json, npm-scripts

The package.json of an Angular library defines the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "node ../../node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build dining",
  "watch": "node ../../node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build dining --watch",
  "postbuild": "node copy-assets.js"
}
```

The postbuild script is executed successfully when I build the library: `npm run build`

but NOT when I call the watch script `npm run watch`:

```
Built dining
Built Angular Package!
 - from: C:\[...]\projects\dining
 - to:   C:\[...]\dist\dining

Compilation complete. Watching for file changes...
```

"dining" is a angular library created by running `npm run ng generate library dining`.

copy-assets.js copies the library's `assets` folder to the `dist` folder.

Node.js version is 12 and npm version is 6.9.0.

How can I have the project built and watched for file modifications and the postbuild script executed in one command?

Comment: postbuild is specifically tied to the build script.

Comment: Indeed. I'm no longer actively involved in that project but the initial script was `"build": "rimraf dist && babel src --out-dir dist --copy-files --source-maps"`. That didn't work on Windows and finally we had to take a different approach altogether by configuring assets as part of the project files thus making the use of postbuild unnecessary. This is an old question that needs to be closed because the answer is more about integration of assets than the building scripts. Thanks for your comment thought.